# AFNetworking -[_NSInlineData URL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, webdav

I'm using AFNetworking to connect to WebDAV servers for our iPad app (Easy Annotate).
Most functions and servers work correctly.

However, when creating a directory on one of the test servers, the app terminates with the following message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSInlineData URL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17cc88a0'
```

Crash location:

```
AFWebDAVManager.m 
- (void)createDirectoryAtURLString:(NSString *)URLString
   withIntermediateDirectories:(BOOL)createIntermediateDirectories
             completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURL *directoryURL, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
   __weak __typeof(self) weakself = self;
   [self MKCOL:URLString success:^(__unused AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSURLResponse *response) {
      if (completionHandler) {
         if([response.class.description isEqualToString:@"_NSZeroData"]) {
            completionHandler(nil, nil);
         }
         else {
            completionHandler([response URL], nil); <-- CRASH !!!
         }
      }
   } ...
```

'response' (see above) is of type _NSInlineData with value:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>
```

I've found similar threads, which suggest adding $(inherited) to the 'other linker flags'. This did not solve the issue (or I made a mistake ;))

Any ideas what might cause this crash?

Comment: You seem to have some experience with checking for the class of the response object being something other than `NSURLResponse`.  Why is that?

Comment: We're working with AFNetworking to provide a WebDAV client interface. I made a contribution to the AFWebDAVManager recently (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFWebDAVManager/pull/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just had the same issue, it's a typo in the code.
It should be `completionHandler([operation.response URL], nil);`

Best,
Thomas

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue.
Could have caught it myself if I had checked the response of the other functions ;)